# Procedure tracking in log with proc renaiming

Tags: tcl, rename, proc

I have a custom test tool written in tcl and bash (mainly in tcl, some initial config and check were done by bash). It isn't have an exact starting point, the outside bash (and sometimes the application which is tested) call specific functions which they find with a "tclIndex" file, created by auto_mkindex.

This tool create a log file, with many "puts" function, which is directed to the file location.

Most of the functions have a "trackBegin" function call at the beginning, and one "trackEnd" function at the end of it. These two get the functions name as parameter. This help us to track where is the problem.

Sadly, this tracker was forgotten in some modification in the near past, and its not even too reliable because its not going to track if there is any abnormal exit in the function. Now, i tried to remove all of them, and create a renamed _proc to override the original and place this two tracker before and after the execution of the function itself.

But i have a lots of error (some i solved, but i dont know its the best way, some are not solved at all, so i'm stuck), these are the main ones:

1. Because there is no exact entry point, where should i define and how, this overrided proc, to work on all of the procedures in this execution? Some of my files had to be manually modified to _proc to work (mostly the ones where there are code outside the procedures and these files as scripts were called, not functions through the tclIndex, the function called ones are all in a utils folder, and only there, maybe it can help).
2. In the tracker line i placed a "clock" with format, and its always cause abnormal exit.
3. I had problems with the returned values (if there was one, and some time when there isn't). Even when that was a return, or Exit.

So my question is in short:
How can i solve an overrided proc function, which will write into a logfile a "begin" and "end" block before and after the procedure itself (The log file location was gained from the bash side of this tool), when there is no clear entry point in this tool for the tcl side, and use an auto_mkindex generated procedure index file?

Thanks,
Roland.

Comment: Might not solve the immediate problem, but have a look at the tcllib logger trace functionality, as it provides a working system for enter/exit tracing of procedures with zero runtime cost when disabled. ( http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/log/logger.html#32 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested

Assuming your bash script does something like

```
tclsh file.tcl
```

You could do

```
tclsh instrumented.tcl file.tcl
```

where instrumented.tcl would contain

```
proc trackBegin {name} {...}
proc trackEnd {name output info} {...}

rename proc _proc
_proc proc {name args body} {
    set new_body [format {
            trackBegin %s
            catch {%s} output info
            trackEnd %s $output $info
        } $name $body $name]
    _proc $name $args $new_body
}

source [lindex $argv 0]
```

See the [`return`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/return.htm) and  [`catch`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/a.htm) pages for what to do with the `info` dictionary.

You'll have to show us some of your code to provide more specific help, particularly for your `clock` error.

Comment: It might be easier to use `try`…`finally` in 8.6…

Comment: I tried with your method, and its clearly a progress. There are some new information:
TCL version is: 7.6.x (according to the config check)
Found the point, where the first tcl was file was called, and placed a modified version of your example coda into there.
Some parts is working, but its crash when it start to call the first procedure from the tclIndex. I found out, that its generated empty. I know that this code is called under these new trackers, but i don't know, why its not working now.

Comment: An other problem is, that my log now contain a lot of "::tcl::tm::..." like lines for every tcl library functions too. How can i made it so the standard functions not logged out, only the ones from my 'utils' folder (these are listed into the tclIndex)?

Comment: Perhaps you'll have to use something like `if {[string match ::tcl* [namespace current]]} {set new_body $body} else { ... }` -- maybe not "namespace current", maybe `$name`. Test and see

Comment: Some of the problems are solved by this method, the newest is with the enviroment variables.
This old tool use a lot of env variable to communicate with multiple part of it. Now because the original entry point was modified (placed 1 level up in the stack) with the tracker file, the enviroment variables not working. The ones defined in functions in the original file were not accessable outside of them. I tried to made them global on function level, or on file level, but nothing solved the problem. Any idea?
(I'm still trying to block out the standard procedure trace)

Comment: That sounds unrelated to this question. It also sounds like you need to completely refactor your code base ;) Good luck.

Comment: Yes, i feared that. This big pile of ... is an old tool, which was not maintained for a long time, and nobody left from the original team who created it.

Comment: I tracked back the problem. Its in this part:
source [lindex $argv 0]
In this script (which is the original starting point), there are multiple proc, and a main part. But in the main part, the proc calls didn't happens. If i take out this tracker file, its working just right. What could have cause it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to use execution tracing for this, with the addition of the execution tracing being done in an execution trace on `proc` (after all, it's *just a regular Tcl command*). In particular, we can do this:

```
proc addTracking {cmd args} {
    set procName [lindex $cmd 1]
    uplevel 1 [list trace add execution $procName enter [list trackBegin $procName]]
    uplevel 1 [list trace add execution $procName leave [list trackEnd $procName]]
}
proc trackBegin {name arguments operation} {
    # ignore operation, arguments might be interesting
    ...
}
proc trackEnd {name arguments code output operation} {
    # ignore operation, arguments might be interesting
    ...
}
trace add execution proc leave addTracking
```

It doesn't give you *quite* the same information, but it does allow you to staple code around the outside non-invasively.